# React Native: Component Not Rendering on Android Emulator

Tags: react-native, create-react-app

[image]

"I'm developing a React Native project and facing an issue where none of my UI components are displaying on the Android emulator. My **`Layout`** component consists of a simple interface using **`<View>`** and **`<Text>`**, and there seems to be no errors in the code. Despite starting the Expo development server with the **`-c`** option to clear the cache, the screen remains blank. I've tried restarting the emulator and reloading the app multiple times with no effect."

1. Ensuring my React Native code is correct and contains no visible errors, particularly within the **`Layout`** component that uses **`<View>`** and **`<Text>`** elements.
2. Restarting the Android emulator multiple times to see if it was a temporary glitch.
3. Clearing the Expo development server cache with the **`expo start -c`** command to ensure that there were no stale builds interfering with the display.
4. Reloading the app on the emulator to refresh the runtime environment.
5. Checking the emulator's network status to ensure it's connected and capable of loading any external resources if needed.

What I expected: After confirming that the code was error-free and performing the above steps, I expected to see the **`Layout`** component rendered on the emulator, showing the simple interface with the text '테스트 화면입니다'. Instead, the emulator continues to display a blank screen with no UI elements from the app visible."

Comment: Try to give style to Text component

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

It's seem the Text `color` is `white`, try change this:

```
<Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Some Text</Text>
```